# How to zoom in a QgraphicsView using pushbuttons?

Tags: c++, qt, zooming

I'm building a very simple image editor on Qt creator.I have my image displayed on a QGraphicsView and i want to give the user the ability to zoom in and out by a pushbutton.

I've searched a lot and found how to zoom in and out through the mouse wheel.As i am very new to Qt i can't adjust it to the pushbutton because i don't understand everything clearly.

I' ve tried this(without understanding completely what i'm doing)but the result isn't the wanted.It zooms in only once and quite abruptly.I want a smoother zoom and as many times as i want.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    QMatrix matrix;
    ui->graphicsView->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorViewCenter);
    matrix.scale(1.0,1.0);
    ui->graphicsView->setMatrix(matrix);
    ui->graphicsView->scale(1,-1);
}
```

I would be very grateful if you guys can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how I implemented zooming in my subclass of QGraphicsView.  Note that you'd need to pass in different values of "zoom" to get different magnifications as the zoom factor is an absolute value, not a relative one.

(The optMousePos argument can be set to point to a QPoint indicating the spot that should be the central-point of the zoom transformation, or it can be left NULL if you don't care about that.  I use it because I zoom in and out based on the user turning the wheel in his mouse, and when doing that, the user usually wants to zoom in towards the point where his mouse point is currently positioned, rather than in towards the center of the graphics area)

```
 qreal _zoom = 0.0;

 [...]

 void MyQGraphWidgetSubclass :: SetZoomFactor(qreal zoom, const QPoint * optMousePos)
 {
    if ((zoom != _zoom)&&(zoom >= 0.02f)&&(zoom <= 1000000.0f))
    {
       QPointF oldPos;
       if (optMousePos) oldPos = mapToScene(*optMousePos);

       // Remember what point we were centered on before...
       _zoom = zoom;
       QMatrix m;
       m.scale(_zoom, _zoom);
       setMatrix(m);

       if (optMousePos)
       {
          const QPointF newPos = mapFromScene(oldPos);
          const QPointF move   = newPos-*optMousePos;
          horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(move.x() + horizontalScrollBar()->value());
          verticalScrollBar()->setValue(move.y() + verticalScrollBar()->value());
       }
    }
 }

 void MyQGraphWidgetSubclass :: wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)
 {
    QPoint pos = event->pos();
    SetZoomFactor(_zoom*pow(1.2, event->delta() / 240.0), &pos);
    event->accept();
 }
```